# MFC Control similar to "Column view" in Mac OS X Finder

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am looking for a MFC control that I can use that looks/acts similar to column view in a Mac Finder window. That is, has a tree like structure in a column format, where the selection in the first column affects what appears in the second column, and so on. (However instead of viewing contents of folders I would be displaying strings retrieved from a database.)

The only thing (that I am aware of) that slightly comes close is List Control. Is there any way to edit a list control to do what I want?

[Also, please give me a link if there is a similar question answered already.]

Thanks in advance.

Picture of Mac OS X column view for reference: (Source: osxdaily.com)
[image: mac os x column view]

Comment: You can try something like  http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/treeview/misc-advanced/article.php/c705/TreeList--Multi-column-tree-control.htm

Comment: Is the control the basis for your application?  If it is, have you looked at creating it with the Explorer style?

Comment: Hi @rrirower, no it's not. Basically when they select a data source and click 'view details', a dialog will appear with the to-be implemented control. They should then be able to select a choice in the first column, and the next column(s) will update accordingly. The control will not be editable.

I guess an alternative way to implement this would be to have multiple list controls/listbox controls? Each list would act as a column...

Comment: You may also want to take a look at building an [ATL composite control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s86kdzd.aspx) that itself contains a tree control and several lists.